# Speech To Text API Read Timeout

Tags: python, ibm-watson

Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm writing a program for my master thesis. This program uses the IBM Watson Speech to Text API.
I connect to the API using this code. Which WORKS!

```
   with open(files, 'rb') as audio_file:
        Transcript_json = json.loads( json.dumps(
        service.recognize(
            audio=audio_file,
            content_type='audio/wav',            
            timestamps=False,
            speech_detector_sensitivity=0.5,
            model="de-DE_Multimedia",
            end_of_phrase_silence_time=0.9,
            split_transcript_at_phrase_end=True,
            audio_metrics=True,
            word_confidence=True).get_result(),
            indent=2))
```

but as soon as the filesize is larger then 40mb I get this error:

```
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:449, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    445         except BaseException as e:
    446             # Remove the TypeError from the exception chain in
    447             # Python 3 (including for exceptions like SystemExit).
    448             # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 449             six.raise_from(e, None)
    450 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

File <string>:3, in raise_from(value, from_value)

File c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:444, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    443 try:
--> 444     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    445 except BaseException as e:
    446     # Remove the TypeError from the exception chain in
    447     # Python 3 (including for exceptions like SystemExit).
    448     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.

File c:\Python310\lib\http\client.py:1374, in HTTPConnection.getresponse(self)
   1373 try:
-> 1374     response.begin()
   1375 except ConnectionError:
...
--> 578     raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
    579 elif isinstance(e, _InvalidHeader):
    580     raise InvalidHeader(e, request=request)

ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.au-syd.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

The weird thing is, it worked before with larger than 40 MB files, but not where I am at now.
The API is able to handle up to 100 MB of upload at once.

TLDR: Code works sometimes at a different place, but not at home.

What is the cause for such a time out error?
Is it the limit of my internet upload speed?

Can you help me here?

Comment: problem can make internet connection and I don't know if you can change it. Maybe it needs faster or better connection.

Comment: I tried it with a powerful upload now at a different place, And it did not work. I don't know what the problem is. Does someone? I will try a different PC now.